# Exclude a directory from GitLab's merge request diff

Tags: diff, gitlab

is it possible to exclude a directory from displaying a diff of merge request in GitLab?

We started to version the bower_components folder (1 - to speed up app build, 2 - because bower has no .lock mechanism), but it makes trouble when doing code review - many changed files appear inside bower_components which makes the diff harder to read.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since gitlab 8.8, gitlab support the .gitattributes.

So if your project does not have  `.gitattributes` add it,

and to exclude files for diff, append:

```
*.<whatever> -diff
```

and to exclude directories from a diff:

```
<mydir> -diff
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to still see the diff on my machine, but ignore during gitlab review?

Comment: AFIAC: such attribute does not exist but that would be `-gitlab-diff` (given existing gitlab-language=LANG). 

But seems this recipe stopped working (it used to work). Got  gitlab 13.3.6-ee.
Locally skips diff (only shows "Binary files a/* and b/* differ") but in gitlab UI/MR does show full diff.

Comment: GitLab Community Edition 14.10.0 `-diff` works, but it needs to be merged in master ahead, after then it started to work  

Comment: The .gitattributes should be in the root project directory for it to work in gitlab. This is a difference to the git spec where the file can be in any directory.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27669)

This is a very simple workaround until there is another way to exclude vendor folders, packages, image files, etc. I just destroy the html nodes with javascript. Saving this code as a bookmark in the browser toolbar lets you filter every time you are in the diff page, just clicking in the bookmark.

```
javascript:var q=prompt(“Insert your filter”);if(q!=null){$(“.diff-file:contains(“+q+“)”).detach()}
```

The script lets you specify the route (f.ex. vendor/) or an extension (.jpeg) to delete all nodes that contains that string.